# libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

Trying to run a game & the game opens the closes right away & in the terminal it says "libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate"

I have searched for weeks trying to fix the problem. All I found is

1. Ubuntu has a bug that has not been fixed yet?
2. Nvidia drivers do not have DRI2 Support?

Anyone know how to fix this, Its driving me nuts. I have tried Nouveau drivers and I get even more libEGL warning errors

I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I have a gtx680 and had the nvidia binary 346.59 installed through Ubuntu repo and I was getting your same error.

Then I installed the nouveau, the error went away but I had problems with the GL version (only 3.x supported).

I tried to install again the 346.59, but this time in the "old way", downloading from nv website, switching to console, stopping lightdm and installing them. It worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)